# SQL Server Database Audting for Windows AD group which are having sysadmin server role

Tags: sql

I have been trying to get a solution for this topic.actually I already posted this several times but still I didn't receive any solution.
What I am looking .In our Database environment there more than 1000 users , these users are Windows users and these users are added as members in  several Windows AD Groups based on the DB access requirements.
There are few AD groups which are having Sysadmin server role.
Now the requirements is we need to configure DATABASE AUDIT for those AD groups which are having 'SysAdmin' Server Role.We need to audit for DML operation (Insert, Update,Delete) for all those AD groups which are having 'SysAdmin' Server Role. Please let me know what should be the Database configuration details.I have already tested in different way but I am getting any correct result.